# Query new field in GraphQL in backward compatible manner

Tags: graphql

So there is this new field added to the server API that the client wants to use. But the client also still needs to work with the older installs of the server that don't define that field yet.

Unfortunately when I just include the field, I get error that the field does not exist and only the error and no `data`.

I also tried introspecting whether the field exist, setting `hasNewField` variable and than doing `newField @include(if: $hasNewField)`, but that still gives me error that `newField` does not exist, even if the `hasNewField` variable is false.

Is there any way to conditionally exclude the field or otherwise get the response with the field if it exists and without it if it doesn't without needing two versions of the query?

The server is using Chilli Cream, but I would prefer a generic solution.

Comment: Does you server expose version info? If it does (or can) then you could use that to alter field selections.

Comment: @MichelFloyd every graphql server exposes version info—the schema! The question is how to avoid having a lot of query variants for the different server versions in the supported range.

Comment: I'm not sure there are any GraphQL clients that support this kind of schema versioning. Normally with SaaS applications one can safely assume that servers version ahead of clients but you must have an on-prem solution where it's the other way around. Plus you have to deal with the downstream consequences of missing fields when rendering.

Comment: @MichelFloyd The schema, by principle of being a schema, supports that kind of versioning. And, well, yes, if the client is a web app served from the server, it should never be newer than the server, so then it's not an issue. But there are some integrations that use the same interface and those may need to talk to multiple versions of the server. Which, by the way, does not imply anything about being on-prem by any means, just not being installed together (and possibly done by different teams or companies).

Comment: What I meant is that I don't know of a client that supports multi-schema or variable-schema semantics.